# How to load image files to gtk.gdk.Pixbuf from stream?

Tags: python, pygtk

I have a file picture.jpg, i'm reading it to memory

```
f = open('picture.jpg', 'rb')
pic = f.read()
f.close()
```

How can I convert pic to gtk.gdk.Pixbuf?
I know that there is gdk_pixbuf_new_from_stream() but it appears to be missing from pyGTK :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `Pixbuf` loader:

```
loader = gtk.gdk.PixbufLoader('jpeg')
loader.write(pic)
loader.close()

pixbuf = loader.get_pixbuf()
```